# How can I connect two Activities to the same service?

Tags: android, android-activity, service

Hi I am triing to develop an app which has two different activities let's call them A1 and A2. A1 is the main activity , so it's the one is launched as soon as you open the app, in the A1 there is a button clicking on that you can open the othere Activity A2.In A1 I use a service to connect to a bluetooth sensor I'd like to connect at the same service when I open the second activity A2. How can I do this?
p.s My service is a bound-service

thanks for your help guys hope I have been clear in my question above.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `bindService` instead of `startService`. Check this for a sample code: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

You haven't use `Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE`. It will recreate the service.